# Proofs involving the Least Upper and Greatest Lower Bound Properties

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me with the following question:

> Let $S \subset T \subset \Bbb{R}$, then
>
> - if $T$ is bounded from above, then $\sup S \le \sup T$
> - if $T$ is bounded from below, then $\inf T \le \inf S$
> - if $T$ is bounded, then $\inf T \le \inf S \le \sup S \le \sup T$.

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 1):

We are of course assuming that $S$ and hence $T$ is nonempty. Since $\sup T\ge x$ for all $x\in T$, we must have $\sup T\ge x$ for all $x\in S$.  So, $\sup T$ an upper bound of $S$, hence $\sup S\le\sup T$, since $\sup S$ is the smallest upper bound of $S$.